# How to delete a BST in C++?

Tags: c++, dynamic, binary-search-tree

Can someone please help me figure out how to properly delete my bst implementation ? I know it's a simple problem, but i tried everything. I want to avoid declaring a dynamic array and if it is possible keep the code with this pointer structure( no pun intended). The problem lies in the destructor section. Thanks !

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    struct Tree{
        struct Tree* left;
        struct Tree* right;
        int val;
        Tree(int);
        ~Tree();
        void Print();
    };
    Tree::Tree(int val){
        this->val = val;
        cout<<"insert l/r for node: "<<this->val<<" , type 0 0 - exit"      <<endl;
int l,r;
cin>>l>>r;
if(l and r){
this->left = new Tree(l);
this->right = new Tree(r);
}else if(l==0 and r==0){
    this->left = NULL;
    this->right = NULL;
    return;
}
    }
    Tree::~Tree(){
        if(this->left == NULL and this->right == NULL){
            delete this;
            return;
        }else{
            this->left->~Tree();
            this->right->~Tree();
        }
    }
    void Tree::Print(){
        if(this == NULL) return;
        cout<<this->val<<endl;
        this->left->Print();
        this->right->Print();
    }
    int main(){
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        Tree* newT = new Tree(n);
        newT->Print();
        newT->~Tree();
        //cout<<newT->val<<endl;
        //newT->Print();


    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's seldom any need to do `delete this`, and in a destructor it's actually *fatal*. The destructor is called because someone already *is* doing a `delete` on the object. By doing `delete this` in the destructor you have an infinite recursion.

Also, don't call the `left` and `right` destructors, `delete` them instead. *And* of course in the `main` function you should not call the destructor either, but use `delete`. The only time you should call a destructor explicitly is when have used placement new, which you haven't done.

There are some other flaws as well, like you never checking if the `left` or `right` pointers are null pointers in the `Print` function.

Lastly, if `this` is a null pointer, then you have some serious problem elsewhere, so never any need to check for it.

---

The destructor should simply be

```
~Tree()
{
    delete left;
    delete right;
}
```

If you then do `delete newT` in the `main` function the whole sub-tree will be automatically deleted.

Comment: I understand, but how should i free the memory instead? If i just delete the object newT in the first place, i receive no access to its children .

Comment: @ValentinKostadinov And why do you want to have access to the children if you're deleting the tree?

Comment: Never mind. Thanks guys. I got it and will try to avoid such mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

> How to delete a BST in C++?

Assuming the empty children point to null rather than a sentinel object and assuming the nodes were allocated with `new`, the destructor of a node can be implemented by simply deleting both children:

```
Tree::~Tree() {
    delete left;
    delete right;
}
```

---

> ```
> if(this == NULL)
> ```

This makes little sense. Member functions may not be called on a null pointer.

> ```
> delete this;
> ```

You can not `delete this` within the destructor. It rarely makes sense to `delete this`.

> ```
> newT->~Tree();
> ```

You hardly ever should call destructors explicitly. It will not deallocate the memory, which you now leak.

To deallocate the memory that you allocated with `new`, you must deallocate with `delete`. This will also call the destructor, so calling it separately would be a mistake.